# Plotting rectangle on the frames of a video

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to plot a rectangle over the frames of my video. I want the rectangle to appear on all the frames of the video. Due to the "hold on" that I have applied, I could see my bounding box on only a few of the frames.

```
v = VideoReader('test.mp4');
numFrames = get(v,'NumberOfFrames');
for k=1:numFrames
    image = read(v,k);
    rectangle('Position',[0 0 100 100],'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth', 3);
    hold on;
    imshow(image);  
end
```

When I try to remove the hold on function the rectangle is not getting plotted on the frame. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to remove your hold on the plot, when you go to the next frame. So insert `hold of` after `imshow`

Comment: I tried but its not working .I just see an image with the bounding box plotted on it .But I can't see the other frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the `imshow` and `rectangle` calls so that `imshow` creates a figure that will fit the image first.  Use `rectangle` after `imshow` to finally draw the rectangle.  Finally, use [`drawnow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) after `imshow` so that you flush the graphics buffer and refresh the figure.  You also need `hold on;` and `hold off;` between the `rectangle` call.

```
v = VideoReader('test.mp4');
numFrames = get(v,'NumberOfFrames');
for k=1:numFrames
    image = read(v,k);
    imshow(image);  
    hold on;
    rectangle('Position',[0 0 100 100],'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth', 3);
    hold off;
    drawnow;
end
```

Comment: To be more explicit, its a good practice to instead of just using `hold off` you `clf` at the start of the plotting!

Comment: Thank you. It worked and the bounding box is getting printed on each frame of the video.